# Should I enable SIMD extensions together with CUDA support when building Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

My CPU has support for SSE4.2, AVX2 and FMA.

1. Is there any gain in passing `--copt=-march=native` along with `--config=cuda`?
2. <strike>If all of them are enabled, will Tensorflow choose the fastest one among them for completing a certain task? Is there a precedence order?</strike> GPU is always preferred.
3. <strike>What does `--copt=-mfpmath=both` do?</strike> Allocate more registers (including SSE) for floating point operations? What difference does it make when SSE4.2 is already enabled?

**UPDATE**

I tested ["translate" example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/translate) with 4 different configurations in 2 different machines:

1. In an i5-6200U with 930MX machine:

   - `bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/[...]`

     The "step-time" ranged from 0.65 to 0.81
   - `bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/[...]`

     The "step-time" ranged from 0.66 to 0.89 (I'd consider this noise)
2. In an i7-4770 machine (no GPU):

   - `bazel build -c opt --config=-march=native //tensorflow/tools/[...]`

     The "step-time" ranged from 1.75 - 1.93
   - `bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --config=-march=native //tensorflow/tools/[...]`

     The "step-time" ranged from 1.26 - 1.40 (definitely an improvement)

*UPDATE2:* I meant to pass `--copt=-march=native`, but incorrectly passed `--config=-march=native` instead! From this, I will (lazily) assume that passing `--copt=-march=native` will indeed enable all `--copt` features supported in the current platform.

Comment: -march=native will enable all optimizations available on your machine

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov That is not the case, I believe, from empirical evidence. I just compared building with `-march=native` with no `copt` flags vs. `-march=native` with all 4 `copt` flags. And there was about 24-30% improvement in performance (specifically, "step-time" in translation RNN tutorial). Also, not passing `copt` flags with `march=native` will give warnings that AVX, FMA etc. are not enabled during runtime.

Comment: oh, interesting! That seems to be a bug since official guidance has been to just use -match=native....I think this should be a github issue and fixed, would you like to find an issue? (something like "[docs] building TensorFlow to make use of avx/avx2/fma" with the stats you gave)

Comment: Actually, can you try one more thing: `bazel build --config=opt target`, that's the official way to turn on all optimizations

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov It looks to me like `--config=opt` is the same as `-c opt` which is passed with every build. It probably means just "release build" (i.e. not "debug build"). Right?

Comment: ok, you are right, in head --config=opt also added -march=native, not no mpmath/fma/avx2 flags

Comment: `-march=native` should be enough to enable fma/avx2 for sure. The problem is that `bazel build -c opt --config=-march=native` does nothing in addition to `-c opt`, it silently ignores the unknown config `-march=native`.

Comment: @wicke Then why is it suggested [in docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup#optimizing_cpu_performance) if it was redundant? (or "unknown"?)

Comment: @wicke Oh! Sorry... I mixed up! It was not `--config=-march=native` but `--copt=-march=native`!! I'll have to run the tests again! (EDIT: Well, I'm not gonna run them again, if you are sure about it...)

Comment: Yes, or just use `--config=opt`, which will add a `-march=native` by default. `-march=native` definitely enables the flags, see `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target`.

Comment: @wicke Then why are they different? If `-c opt` was set as "the config", then their performance should be identical, right? Unless `--copt=-mfpmath=both` made all the difference? (./configure runs were identical)

Comment: @wicke The docs says "To be compatible with as wide a range of machines as possible, TensorFlow defaults to only using SSE4.1 SIMD instructions on x86 machines." So I guess `-c opt` does not enable `-march=native` by default? And I will assume that passing `--copt=-march=native` will indeed enable all supported `--copt`s?

Comment: `-c opt` turns on machine independent optimizations (`-O2` if I'm not mistaken). `--config=opt` is something we made to turn on both `-c opt` and whatever you configure in `./configure`, by default `-march=native`.

Comment: And yes, `-c opt --copt=-march-native` is the bare metal way of saying `--config=opt`.

Comment: To further clear the confusion, `-c` flag of bazel is the short for `--compilation_mode`. `--config` gives us multiple configurations we can preset using `bazelrc`. https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/command-line-reference.html

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Ping to correct my incorrect guess that `-c` was `--config`. See the comment above by gunan.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, the following will enable all hardware-specific optimizations in (in TF 1.0rc1 or later):

`bazel build --config=opt`

For GPU support, use

`bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda`

Comment: This does not answer any of my 3 (or 2) questions.

Comment: sorry, I assumed the real question was "how do I make things run as fast as possible"